# Add custom attribute to AAD user in B2B tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure custom attribute for users in AAD B2B tenant. I know this has been discussed on B2C tenants and it is possible there but I am not sure whether it can be done on B2B.

I have found multiple resources discussing this problem but none of them explained whether it is possible on B2B and if yes then how it should be done:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-flow-add-custom-attributes
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1094181/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-user-attributes-in

... and more (I have found some solutions utilizing Microsoft Graph API but this was also mentioned only in context of B2C tenant.)

My goal is to create and set attribute (via CLI) of the regional manager (manager attribute is already filled) for each user in AAD B2B tenant. I do not want users to enter freely whatever they want into input field while they are signing up like shoe size in B2C tenant for example. Is it possible to do something like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To create and set the Custom Attribute to the user, you can make use of Microsoft Graph API:

**To create the Custom Attribute**, execute the below query:

> **`Application.ReadWrite.All`** permission is required to perform the action.

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ObjectIdofApp/extensionProperties
Content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "regionalmanager",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}
```

[image]

**To set the custom Attribute to the user**, execute the below query:

```json
Patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserId

{"extension_{AppClientIDwithout "-"}_customAttribute":"value"}
```

[image]

**To fetch the extension attribute of the user**:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID?$select=displayName,extension_ClientID_regionalmanager
```

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can also create [**Customer Security Attributes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/custom-security-attributes-add?tabs=ms-powershell) like below:

Create a Customer Security Attribute:

[image]

Add attribute set like below:

[image]

Now, you can assign this attribute to the user:

[image]

> I do not want users to enter freely whatever they want into input field while they are signing up like shoe size in B2C tenant for example. Is it possible to do something like that?

This is possible via Azure AD B2C custom policy. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policies-series-validate-user-input).

**Reference:**

[Add custom attributes to self-service sign-up flows - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-flow-add-custom-attributes)